# How to draw/move an image on top of a view on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview

So, I've made a default view for a game

[image: ScreenShot..]
and now I need to add cards that can be moved around on top of the view.

I have only one class so far, `HelloAndroidActivity.java` with the following code:

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

So, how can I go about bringing other images onto this existing view, and manipulating them?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there are many ways to realise that:

I suppose the best way to deal with, would be to use a `SurfaceView` (or, extending a `SurfaceView` to be precise), and deal with the `onDraw` event and print card directly from stored bitmaps.

Like this kind of tutorial :
http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html

I don't think creating plenty of Android controls is a good idea for card games.